# Is it possible to use a macro to create typedefs?

Tags: c++, c

How can I create a typedef using a macro (#define)?

I am, for various reasons, trying to use a macro to do typedef'ing in C. Something along the lines of templates for C++.

As an example, I would expect the preprocessor to expand the `#define` and `typedef` a `struct` whose "content" member is of type `char`:

```
#define DEFINE_FOO_TYPE(content_type__, content_type_name__) \
typedef struct {                                             \
        content_type__ content;                              \
} content_type_name__

DEFINE_FOO_TYPE(char, foo_t);

foo_t foo_var;
foo_var.content = 'g';
```

Apparently that is not the case. Is it possible to do these sort of things in C at all, or is the only way a C++ template?

To preempt questions along the lines of "why don't you just use a C++ template?". The answer is that I'm trying to do it in C because it's fun.

Comment: So what is problem with the above?

Comment: You are typedeffing a struct called 'element_type_name__' instead of the passed parameter 'content_type_name__'

Comment: Yes, you've a typo as @TomKnapen points out. Fix that and you're sorted but remember you'll get no type checking. If you're doing this in C++ you should definitely use templates instead.

Comment: I've corrected the example. It was a typo. But the question still stands. Compiling the above makes gcc say "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘.’ token"

Comment: This is really going to be a mess. Compilers don't generate debug info for macro code, so you will end up with all of this code as not debuggable. Instead of trying to write C++ in C, just write C (funny it's usually the other way around :)).

Comment: Yes, I know it's going to be a mess, but I'm trying to do in C, what is easily done in C++ with templates. More an exercise in whether it can be done in C at all than because I really can't do it in C++.

Comment: Surely you are not just pasting that quoted code into gcc, are you? You can't just execute code outside any function. Put the last line inside a function.

Comment: @DanielKO, please state your comment as an answer cause you are spot on :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted in a comment because I thought it was too trivial, but here it is:

> Surely you are not just pasting that quoted code into gcc, are you? You can't just execute code outside any function. Put the last line inside a function.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#define DEFINE_FOO_TYPE(content_type__, content_type_name__) \
typedef struct {                                             \
    content_type__ content;                              \
} content_type_name__

DEFINE_FOO_TYPE(char, foo_t);

int main() {
    foo_t foo_var;
    foo_var.content = 'g';
    return 0;
}
```

I.e. use `content_type_name__` instead of `element_type_name__`

[Proof of compilation](http://ideone.com/0SBR1)

Comment: OK, that was a stupid typo on my part, but the question still stands. I've corrected the example.

Comment: @colding No, the question obviously doesn't still stand, since the corrected code works ... or rather, it would work if you put executable code inside a function.

Comment: @JimBalter, you are correct. DanielKO is getting the mark as he spottet the issue a few minuttes before you did. Otherwise thanks.

Comment: @colding Tom Knapen deserves at least as much credit as DanielKO. Note that, other than for formatting or other clarity, you should not edit code after posting it, as it invalidates people's responses.

Answer (score 0):

simply put the last two lines of code into main()
or any function it will work for sure.